# .split() not working as expected in IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

I'm using the following to extract variables from a URL contained in a variable.  It works fine in modern browsers but in IE8 it fails on the first variable but succeeds on the second.

```
var p = 'http://sagensundesign.com?height=400&width=300';

/* Get Height */
var h = p.split(/height=([0-9]+)/);
h = h[1];
if (!h) {h = 500};
alert(h);

/* Get Width */
var w = p.split(/width=([0-9]+)/);
w = w[1];
if (!w) {w = 800};
alert(w);
```

**UDPATE:**

Here is the working solution... http://jsfiddle.net/cssguru/B42tM/

Comment: Split has various bugs in its implementation on various web browsers. Some are edge cases, others not. I suggest you take a look at the following to see if you can replicate the bug and then use that information to devise a workaround. http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/cross-browser-split

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you need to use split here?  Can you not just use `match`:

```
var h = p.match(/height=([0-9]+)/)[1];
```

As browsers have some bugs using split with a regex http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/cross-browser-split.  If you do need to use `split` with a regex cross browser you could look at [xregexp](http://xregexp.com/cross_browser/) which is a library that fixes regexs across browsers.

Answer (score 2):

Use p.match(regex) instead:

http://jsfiddle.net/B42tM/3/

```
/* Get Height */
var h = p.match(/height=([0-9]+)/);
h = h[1];
if (!h) {h = 500};
alert(h);

/* Get Width */
var w = p.match(/width=([0-9]+)/);
w = w[1];
if (!w) {w = 800};
alert(w);
```

Answer (score 2):

There have been some valid responses, but you may be interested in a function I use to retrieve `GET` parameters from URLs.

```
var get = function (name, url) { // Retrieves a specified HTTP GET parameter. Returns null if not found.
    url = (typeof (url) === "undefined" ? window.location.href : url);

    var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)");
    var results = regex.exec(url);
    var output = (results ? results[1] : null);

    return output;
};
```

You could use it like this.

```
var url = 'http://sagensundesign.com?height=400&width=300';

var h = get("height",url);
var w = get("width",url);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a normalisation script which should fix the inconcistencies you are seeing. http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/cross-browser-split

Answer (score 0):

You can find both dimensions with a match or exec expression:

```
var p = 'http://sagensundesign.com?height=400&width=300';

var siz=p.match(/((height|width)=)(\d+)/g);


alert(siz)

/*  returned value: (Array)
height=400, width=300
*/
```