# Javascript error in ie8 when accessing array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-8

I have this rather simple function in js/jquery which gets a list of DOM elements (links) and binds a function to the click event:

```
$(".editLink").each(function(){
        $(this).click(function(){
            linkIdParts = $(this).attr("id").split("-");
            linkId = linkIdParts[1];
            editLink(linkId);
        });
    });
```

Everything went fine until we found this bug which occurs only in ie8 when clicking on one of the elements which should execute the click function:
The linkIdParts seems to correctly contain 2 elements (ie. when hovering on the js code iexplorer shows the small popup containing ["editlink","8"]), but the following line returns an error:

```
linkId = linkIdParts[1];
```

"Object doesn't support this property or method"

Any idea on why this straightforward piece of code should be giving problems with ie?

I don't think the problem is related to the html code but here it is:

```
<a class="btn-icon btn editLink" id="editLink-112" jQuery111208742703045535458="14">
<img title="linked offices" class="imgyes centerimg" src="style/css/images/office.png" onremove="null" jQuery111208742703045535458="1899">
</a>
```

Comment: I doubt you've a wrong line in error message. Old IEs are not accurate when pointing to a line caused an error. What is the used jQuery version? Only jQuery 1.X support IE<9.

Comment: I've tried to put a breakpoint on the line immediately before and the line after the one which gives error (I also thought it was the wrong line at the beginning). The browser reached the first breakpoint but after that I got the error (without ever reaching the second one).

Comment: Not sure if it has anything todo with the problem itsself, but you don't have " around your id => `id="editLinks-112"`

Comment: It somehow disappeared after pasting my code. I'll fix it but on my site it's correct.

Comment: possible duplicate of [.split() not working as expected in IE8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9489636/split-not-working-as-expected-in-ie8)